# Why does a PUT 403 show up as Aborted?

Tags: javascript, http, http-put

I've made a dummy django view that accepts `PUT` requests:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^put/.*$', 'put', name='put'),

# views.py
def put(request):
    print request.method
    return HttpResponse()
```

Now, when I try to make a `PUT` xhr call to the view, it returns a 403:

> [27/Sep/2012 22:32:43] "PUT /put/x-unconverted/e02ed7da08d411e2bfa974de2b4d1b84?partNumber=115&uploadId=35UxOsGCCG98rke3VjpazmCy.0ZFpesndJ.XPp5Bw6R2CumfIsYKP5DlBYPY3gh3I0PCwfCg4DqSRttYp75bZg-- HTTP/1.1" 403 156400

(*why* it returns 403, I don't care right now). The REAL problem is this:

[image]

The XHR call returns status 0 (aborted?!), even if the real response was a 403, with content (notice 156400 content length).

**Why doesn't it show the 403 response?**

**EDIT**: the `PUT` request is made like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var path = "/" + u.settings.key;
path += "?partNumber=" + (chunk + 1) + "&uploadId=" + u.upload_id;

var method = "PUT";
var authorization = "AWS " + u.settings.access_key + ":" + signature;
var blob = u.file.slice(start, end); // mozSlice / webkitSlice, depending on browser
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progress_handler);
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", handler);
xhr.addEventListener("error", error_handler);
xhr.addEventListener("timeout", error_handler);

xhr.open(method, /*u.settings.host*/ "http://localhost:8000/put" + path, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", date);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authorization);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", u.settings.content_type);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + u.file.name);

xhr.send(blob);
```

Comment: How did you make the PUT XHR request?

Comment: @KayZhu Check out my edit; it's basically a PUT request for Amazon S3, but going to the django development server.

Answer (score 0):

I think browser is assuming that it is a cross-domain request when it receives 403 which means forbidden access. That's the reason why browser is not handling data back to the javascript code that made the request. Server should send 'Action-Control-Allow-Origin' header for all the responses.